# colouring oceans (using naturalearth data) - issues with rendering

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, clipping

To add oceans to a map, I am looking into using the rnaturalearth package together with ocean50 data.

```
devtools::install_github("ropenscilabs/rnaturalearth")

library(rnaturalearth)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggalt)

ocean50 <- ne_download(scale = 50, type = 'ocean', category = 'physical')
plot(ocean50, col="lightblue")
o<-fortify(ocean50)
gg<-ggplot() +
  geom_cartogram(aes(long, lat, map_id = id), data=o, map=o, fill="lightblue")
```

but it appears that the American continent disappeared.

[image]

Moreover, when I try

```
gg + coord_map("ortho", orientation = c(4.22, 18.35, 0))+theme_map()
```

the continent and not the oceans are coloured

[image]

Any suggestion on how to fix this? Is there an easy way to clip based on orientation?

Comment: http://www.winwaed.com/blog/2010/01/18/polar-maps-and-projections-part-2-implementation/ hints to using only the polygons of the hemisphere you are interested in